# Using the R Shiny Date Range input with the DataTables ouput

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use the `dateRangeInput` in the Shiny R package along with the built-in output `DataTable`, but when I run the application I get the error:

```
Error in >=.default(date, input$dates[1]) : 
  comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

My code is :

```
 ui.R

          dashboardBody(
                      fluidRow(
                         dateRangeInput("dates", "Date Range",
                                        start = head(comp.reg.df$date,1),
                                        end = tail(comp.reg.df$date,1),
                                        startview = "month",
                                         separator = " to "),

                         dataTableOutput("table")
                      )
    )



server.R

        shinyServer <- function(input, output) {

         reg.final <- reactive({

    comp.reg.final <- comp.reg.df[date >= input$dates[1] & date <= input$dates[2]]

            return (comp.reg.final)

          })


          output$table <- renderDataTable(reg.final(),
                                          options = list(pageLength = 10))



          }
```

Where `comp.reg.df` is a dataframe that has a column name `date` of character class. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try as.Date(input$dates[1]) - same of course for  input$dates[2] ;)

Comment: Thanks @user3502164. But I get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that comp.reg.df is a data frame so you need a comma in your call to it.

Try:

```
   comp.reg.final <- comp.reg.df[which(comp.reg.df$date >= input$dates[1] & comp.reg.df$date <= input$dates[2]),]
```